# Object have data but when opened it's empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

**Framework:** React

So when I'm running the code below I console.log the objects.
When looking at the first object is pushed to the array then it contains text but when looking at the array of objects afterward it's empty.

The index 5 that is marked should be the object being pushed in the array in the red rectangle.

How come?

**The code**

```
    const SplitHtml = () => {
  const string =
    '<p><strong>Add and edit text here. <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.google.com">This is a link</a> Select text to format it.</strong></p><p>&nbsp;</p><p></p>'

  const stringArray = string.split(/(<[^>]+>)/)
  let textArray = []
  let object = {}

  for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    console.log(i, object.text)
    if (stringArray[i] === undefined) break
    // Print out
    if (stringArray[i].startsWith("<") && object.text && object.text.length > 0) {
      console.log(i, " push")
      textArray = [...textArray, object]
    }
    // Elements
    else if (stringArray[i] === "<p>") {
      object.type = "text"
    } else if (stringArray[i] === "<h1>") {
      object.type = "headline"
      object.importance = "1"
    } else if (stringArray[i] === "<h2>") {
      object.type = "headline"
      object.importance = "2"
    } else if (stringArray[i] === "<h3>") {
      object.type = "headline"
      object.importance = "3"
    } else if (stringArray[i] === "<h4>") {
      object.type = "headline"
      object.importance = "4"
    } else if (stringArray[i] === "<h5>") {
      object.type = "headline"
      object.importance = "5"
    } else if (stringArray[i] === "<h6>") {
      object.type = "headline"
      object.importance = "6"
    } else if (stringArray[i].startsWith("<a")) {
      object.type = "link"
    }
    // Style
    else if (stringArray[i] === "<strong>") {
      object.bold = true
    } else if (stringArray[i] === "</strong>") {
      object.bold = false
    } else if (stringArray[i] === "<i>") {
      object.italic = true
    } else if (stringArray[i] === "</i>") {
      object.italic = false
    }
    // Text
    else if (!stringArray[i].startsWith("<")) {
      object.text = stringArray[i]
    }
  }
  console.log(textArray)
}
```

**The screenshot**

[image]

Comment: It is probably being modified after the initial console.log.

Comment: Your `forEach` callback is manipulating the same object instance, so it keeps overwriting its previous key values. The preview you see is what was in there when it was logged but had changed by the time you opened it (at which point the console reevaluates the contents)

Comment: Thanks for the fast answers! But you see that `textArray = [...textArray, object];` so when console logging the array afterwards all the objects are empty as well — Even though it console logged one with text and afterwards pushed it to the array — How come?

Comment: Because they are all the same object instance. Move the `let object = {}` inside the callback and you will have a different instance each iteration

Comment: I updated the thread with better information — The object should be outside the loop because it shouldn't be reset each iteration.

Comment: It was a deep copy problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to deep copy by using `const pushObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object))` before I pushed that new pushObject into the array.

Otherwise, the old object was already referenced as stated in @a--m post below!

Answer (score 1):

If you hover the info icon you will see this message:
`Value below was evaluate just now`

What this means is that the console.log will render what the object value was by that time, but if you are mutating an object the value will change and when you open that object in the console it will reflect the current state.

See the following example:

[image]

The `ref` object is modified and when expanded it will show and match the current value.

Comment: Yes, thanks! But if you look at the new information I added in the start thread — How can it become like that? Even if I do a hard copy with JSON.parse and JSON.stringify it's still empty the text in the object.